# How to embed LaTeX code into an R-Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, mathjax

I am creating an R-Shiny application where the user will select a choice from a drop down menu and depending on what is selected a different set of LaTeX output will be displayed.
I am attempting to use the withMathJax() function but it is not outputting the text to me in a desired setting. This is a snippet of how it is being displayed in my R-Shiny application:
[image]

This is how the text is being saved in my code:

```
var1 = "\\subsection{Normal Linear Regression}
\\subsubsection{Conditions}
\\begin{itemize}
    \\item Independence of observations. All data used must be independent of one another (something which is \\textbf{not true} in time series data)
    \\item Linearity between predictor variables and response variable
    \\item Error term is normally distributed with mean 0 and constant variance
    \\item Little or no collinearity between predictors
\\end{itemize}"
```

This is how it is being stored as part of the ui:

```
fluidRow(
          column(width = 6,
                 uiOutput("ContinuousShow1")
                 ),
```

And this is how its displayed in the server function:

```
output$ContinuousShow1 <- renderUI({
    withMathJax(
      helpText(var1)
    )
  })
```

Any ideas on how to make it display correctly?

Comment: Hi, MathJax is not LaTeX. You can use some $\\bullet$ to do the bullet points.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Well just type $\\bullet$. Otherwise you can convert LaTeX to HTML with the help of Pandoc.